# How to Register a Service in Mac OS?

Tags: c#, macos, monomac

I am experimenting with Mono, MonoMac, and C#. I try to write a simple application based on a service for Mac OS. I followed Apple's [developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/Articles/providing.html) on implementation of service providers.

My problem is: how to register a service. In Objective-C I would call the setServicesProvider method of NSApplication. But it seems that there is no such a method in MonoMac. Is this right? In the mono docs I found that NSApplication is supposed to have a services provider with a corresponding setter. But calling the SetServicesProvider like:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); 
NSApplication.SetServicesProvider(myClass);
```

results in the following error:

```
Error CS0117: `MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication' does not contain a definition for `SetServicesProvider' (CS0117)
```

What is the problem here? Is the ServicesProvider property part of the 10% of AppKit that is not implemented so far (The Status section on the MonoMac project page says under "AppKit (About 10% left to be done))?

Alternatively, I tried to find a class NSRegisterServicesProvider as suggested in the apple developer's example. But I cannot find such a class.

Anyone knows how to register a service using MonoMac? Could you please point me to a solution, an example?

I am using MonoDevelop 3.1.1 and `Xamarin.Mac` development add-in (Version 3.1.1). The latter is at least what is stated in the add-in manager. The version information tab in the "About MonoDevelop" says "Xamarin.Mac: Not Installed". But I think the latter is not right since I get for example access to the `NSApplication` class using `MonoMac.AppKit`.

I asked this question on the Mono - OSX mailing list but unfortunately I did get no reply so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrapped by a property in `Xamarin.Mac`. Try;

`NSApplication.SharedApplication.ServicesProvider = new myClass()`

The hardest thing I have found with these services is getting the `info.plist` declaration correct.